# rsnapshot, multiple backup destinations

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

```
###########################
# SNAPSHOT ROOT DIRECTORY #
###########################

# All snapshots will be stored under this root directory.
#
snapshot_root   /.snapshots/


###############################
### BACKUP POINTS / SCRIPTS ###
###############################

# LOCALHOST
# 1st dir to backup
backup  /home/username/some_dir/to_backup/  localhost/
# 2nd dir to backup
backup  /home/username/another_dir/to_backup/   localhost/
#backup /foo/bar/   localhost/  one_fs=1, rsync_short_args=-urltvpog
#backup_script  /usr/local/bin/backup_pgsql.sh  localhost/postgres/
```

Now with these settings, all backups will have destination in `.snapshots` dir
under my root directory, keeping hierarchy.

So I will have:

```
/.snapshots/localhost/home/username/some_dir/to_backup
```

Is it possible somehow to have that `2nd dir to backup` have another
destination, like for example my `/home/username/backup-scripts`?

Answer (score 15):

copy existing .conf with another name `sudo cp /etc/rsnapshot.conf /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf`
And make some changes specific for this directory using

```
sudo nano /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf
```

save and run the second .conf file with command `sudo rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf configtest` if u get syntax ok , then make a dry run with `sudo rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf -t hourly` then configure cronjobs for 2nd directory by using `sudo nano /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot` u can just add set of lines below the already existing lines in there,

```
30 */4 * * * root /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf hourly 
01 1 * * * root /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf daily 
01 2 * * 0 root /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf weekly
01 5 1 * * root /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf monthly
01 8 1 1 * root /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot-2ndname.conf yearly
```

Comment: Damn, this is not how I imagined it. I have dozens of drive partitions and wanted the .`snapshots` dir to reside on the same partition. A lot of redundant configuration. It's like `httpd` where you have to have an `httpd.conf` for every instance, unlike python's SimpleHTTPDServer

Answer (score 5):

Not without creating another config with a different `snapshot_root` then running it with `rsnapshot -c new.conf`